# Algorithm for exclude combinations with unique value using php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sum

The algoritham i'm trying different combinations of values will able to give my exact or approx output sum of values

I have attached image for the detail explanation , I have created column total as sum of each row value and finally I have sum all the total value, the whole total sum value is to be my expected output value.

So I'm trying to take a combination of each row sum and like to get total sum value

My algorithm i have searched in google below

```
function extractList($array, &$list, $temp = array()) {
    if (count($temp) > 0 && ! in_array($temp, $list))
        $list[] = $temp;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i ++) {
        $copy = $array;
        $elem = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
        if (sizeof($copy) > 0) {
            $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
            sort($add);
            extractList($copy, $list, $add);
        } else {
            $add = array_merge($temp, array($elem[0]));
            sort($add);
            if (! in_array($temp, $list)) {
                $list[] = $add;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";

$sum = 32 ; //SUM
$array = array(5.14327,5.72355,5.91794,4.8209,8.69933,4.12977,4.12977,2.92791,2.36829,2.21819,1.33759,1.72278,1.72278,0.589,1.06405,0.6387,0.6387,1.68995,2.51669,3.97842,2.38058,2.17175,4.88264,5.84811,6.14215);

$list = array();

# Extract All Unique Conbinations
extractList($array, $list);

#Filter By SUM = $sum
$list = array_filter($list,function($var) use ($sum) { return(array_sum($var) == $sum);});

#Return Output
print_r($list);
```

[Attached Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z41bH.png)

Comment: Your image doesn't make a lot of sense, the green column does not contain row sums.

Comment: You going to respond?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how you determine approximate equality. A percentage? Or an absolute amount? That's what you need in your filter lambda function.

```
// outside lambda
$error = $sum * 5 / 100;// 5%, or
$error = 0.02;// an absolute
...
// inside lambda
return abs(array_sum($var) - $sum) <= $error;
```